# Convert character dates in r (weird format)

Tags: r, date

I have columns that are named "X1.1.21", "X12.31.20" etc.
I can get rid of all the "X"s by using the substring function:

```
names(df) <- substring(names(df), 2, 8)
```

I've been trying many different methods to change "1.1.21" into a date format in R, but I'm having no luck so far. How can I go about this?

Comment: Column names in R's `data.frame` objects typically are checked and modified so that they follow simple rules. You can likely prevent them being munged that way by including `check.names=FALSE` (or similar) in whichever function you used to read in the data. Having said that, if you want to remove the leading `X`, just use `gsub("^X", "", names(df))`.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R doesn't like column names that start with numbers (hence you get `X` in front of them). However, you can still force R to allow column names that start with number by using `check.names = FALSE` while reading the data.

If you want to include date format as column names, you can use :

```
df <- data.frame(X1.1.21 = rnorm(5), X12.31.20 = rnorm(5))
names(df) <- as.Date(names(df), 'X%m.%d.%y')
names(df)
#[1] "2021-01-01" "2020-12-31"
```

However, note that they look like dates but are still of type 'character'

```
class(names(df))
#[1] "character"
```

So if you are going to use the column names for some date calculation you need to change it to date type first.

```
 as.Date(names(df))
```

Comment: When I try using as.Date, it changes from "1/22/20" to "0020-01-22". Is there a way to change it to "2020-01-22"?

Comment: Are you sure you are copying it correctly? I think you are using `as.Date(names(df), 'X%m.%d.%Y')` and not `as.Date(names(df), 'X%m.%d.%y')`. You should use `%y` and not `%Y`.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: Oh actually, I have other columns before this date columns like "id" and "street name". when I try names(df)[3:ncol(df)] <- as.Date(...), it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to subset from both the ends. `names(df)[3:ncol(df)] <- as.Date(names(df)[3:ncol(df)], 'X%m.%d.%y')`

Comment: When I do that, the output becomes a random number like "18283" etc

Comment: I see. Try `names(df)[3:ncol(df)] <- as.character(as.Date(names(df)[3:ncol(df)], 'X%m.%d.%y'))`